# Wildcard character asterisk in route path throws error

Tags: haskell, yesod

A simple yesod server code with a single handler for all GET requests i wrote as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes, MultiParamTypeClasses,
TemplateHaskell, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Yesod
data Links = Links
mkYesod "Links" [parseRoutes|
/* HomeR GET
|]
instance Yesod Links
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Go to page 1!|]
main = warpDebug 3000 Links
```

It throws a cryptic error as,

```
 Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
      Invalid type: ""
    Code: mkYesod
            "Links"
            ([Yesod.Routes.TH.Types.ResourceLeaf
                (Yesod.Routes.TH.Types.Resource
                   "HomeR"
                   []
                   (Yesod.Routes.TH.Types.Methods (Data.Maybe.Just []) ["GET"])
                   []
                   GHC.Types.True)])
```

I copied the working code from a blog and removed all but one route, added wildcard character `*` to the single routepath as `[parseRoutes| /* HomeR GET \]` to make it the handler for all urls.
And, the code no longer works.

Comment: AFAIK you need a *Type* that is an instance of `PathMultiPiece` (like `Texts`) after the `*` ([see here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers)) and of course your handler should take care of these parts (with `Texts` you should add an argument of type `[Text]`)

Comment: i am a newbie to haskell. i see, PathMultiPiece has two methods, `toPathMultiPiece` and `fromPathMultiPiece`. By overriding this, how can i write a get handler? i removed getHomeR and added this code `data Page = Page [Text]
instance PathMultiPiece Page where
  toPathMultiPiece (Page x y z) = x : y : z
  fromPathMultiPiece (x:y:z) = Just $ Page x y z
  fromPathMultiPiece _       = Nothing
`. But still the error is there....

Comment: did you have a look at the link I gave you to the **Yesod documentation**? there a `/wiki/*` route is defined together with a handler and I think you could do the same here - just use `/*Texts` and `getHomeR parts = ...` (you don't even have to use the parts - although it might be strange)

Comment: thanks a lot, Carsten... just using `getHomeR = .....` didn't work.. but adding `getHomeR parts = ` made it work.

Comment: glad could help - i make it into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add an type that is an instance of `PathMultiPiece` after the `*` like this:

```
/*Texts HomeR GET
```

([`Texts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.9.1/docs/Yesod-Core-Dispatch.html#t:Texts), which is just a synonym for `[Text]` is an instance because `Text` is an instance of `PathPiece`) and of course you have to add it as an argument to your handler:

```
getHomeR :: [Text] -> Handler Html
getHomeR parts = defaultLayout [whamlet|Go to page 1!|]
```

you can read more about this in the [yesod documentation](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers)